# nzv filter for continuous features in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am a beginner to practical machine learning using R, specifically caret.
I am currently applying a random forest algorithm for a microbiome dataset. The values are relative abundance transformed so if my features are columns, sum of all columns for Row 1 == 1

It is common to have cells with a lot of 0 values.
Typically I used the default nzv preprocessing feature in caret.

Default:
a. One unique value across the entire dataset
b. few unique values relative to the number of samples in the dataset (<10 %)
c. large ratio of the frequency of the most common value to the frequency of the second most common value (cutoff used is > 19)

So is this function not actually calculating variance, but determining a frequency of occurence of features and filter based on the frequency? If so is it only safe to use it for discrete/categorical variables?

I have a number of features in my dataset ~12k, many of which might be singletons or have a zero value for a lot of features.

My question: Is nzv suitable for such a continuous, zero inflated dataset?
What pre-processing options would you recommend?
When I use default nzv I am dropping a tonne of features (from 12k to ~2,700 k) in the final table

I do want a less noisy dataset but at the same time do not want to loose good features

This is my first question and I am willing to re-revise, edit and resubmit if required.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks a tonne!

Comment: Requests for advice on how to best do statistics should go to CrossValidate.com. Once you have a clear algorithm in mind, then SO is appropriate.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. Is there a way to port the question? I wondered whether to post here or not since I was not posting any actual code but also felt that it was a relevant over-arching pre-processing question.

Comment: Two possibilities. 1) Wait for another 4 people to agree with me and vote for migration. 2) Copy question. Delete here. Repost on CV.com.